# Elasticsearch: total term frequency and doc count from given set of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, term-vectors

I am trying to get total term frequency and document count from given set of documents, but _termvectors in elasticsearch returns ttf and doc_count from all documents within the index. Is there any way so that I can specify list of documents (document ids) so that result will based on those documents only.

Below are documents details and query to get total term frequency:

**Index details:**

```
PUT /twitter
{ "mappings": {
    "tweets": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"english"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Document Details:**

```
PUT /twitter/tweets/1
{
  "name":"Hello bar"
}

PUT /twitter/tweets/2
{
  "name":"Hello foo"
}

PUT /twitter/tweets/3
{
  "name":"Hello foo bar"
}
```

It will create three document with ids 1, 2 and 3. Now suppose tweets with ids 1 and 2 belongs to user1 and 3 belong to another user and I want to get the termvectors for user1.

Query to get this result:

```
GET /twitter/tweets/_mtermvectors
{
  "ids" : ["1", "2"],
  "parameters": {
      "fields": ["name"],
      "term_statistics": true,
      "offsets":false,
      "payloads":false,
      "positions":false
  }
}
```

Response:

```
    {
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "twitter",
      "_type": "tweets",
      "_id": "1",
      "_version": 1,
      "found": true,
      "took": 1,
      "term_vectors": {
        "name": {
          "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 7,
            "doc_count": 3,
            "sum_ttf": 7
          },
          "terms": {
            "bar": {
              "doc_freq": 2,
              "ttf": 2,
              "term_freq": 1
            },
            "hello": {
              "doc_freq": 3,
              "ttf": 3,
              "term_freq": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "twitter",
      "_type": "tweets",
      "_id": "2",
      "_version": 1,
      "found": true,
      "took": 1,
      "term_vectors": {
        "name": {
          "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 7,
            "doc_count": 3,
            "sum_ttf": 7
          },
          "terms": {
            "foo": {
              "doc_freq": 2,
              "ttf": 2,
              "term_freq": 1
            },
            "hello": {
              "doc_freq": 3,
              "ttf": 3,
              "term_freq": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here we can see `hello` is having doc_count 3 and ttf 3. How can I make it to consider only documents with given ids.

One approach I am thinking is to create different index for different users. But I am not sure if this approach is correct. With this approach indices will increase with users. Or can there be another solution?

Answer (score 2):

To obtain term doc count on a subset of documents you may try to use simple aggregations.

You will have to enable `fielddata` in the mapping of the field (though it might become tough on memory, check out the [documentation page about `fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) for more details):

```
PUT /twitter
{ 
  "mappings": {
    "tweets": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"english",
          "fielddata": true,
          "term_vector": "yes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation:

```
POST /twitter/tweets/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_term_doc_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will be:

```
{
  "hits": ...,
  "aggregations": {
    "my_term_doc_count": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "hello",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "bar",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "foo",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find a way to calculate `total_term_frequency` on the subset of documents though, I'm afraid it can't be done.

I would suggest to compute term vectors offline with [`_analyze` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/indices-analyze.html) and store them in a separate index explicitly. In this way you will be able to use simple aggregations to compute also total term frequency. Here I show an example usage of `_analyze` API.

```
POST twitter/_analyze
{
  "text": "Hello foo bar"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hello",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "foo",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "bar",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope that helps!